# Problems conenctng HDMI splitter with SPDIF audio out to AV Amp with TOSLINK

Tags: audio, hdmi, splitter, digital-audio, spdif

Have purchased and HDMI splitter with SPDIF out for audio.AV amp has Toslink input. Connectng TOSLINL Cable doesn't fit splitter output port (Toslink male  end too big forspillter SPDIF female output socket. Solution?

Comment: What is the model number of the splitter?
And how do you know it should fit to TOSLINK Cable?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you haven't shown us any pictures this is a tricky one, but you might be facing one of the following problems:

- TOSLINK connectors are not square, they will only fit one way,
  usually the flanged corners are supposed to be down.
- You need a mini-TOSLINK adapter, or your cable is mini-TOSLINK.
- Most SPDIF interfaces are coaxial these days perhaps one of your units has RCA-type connectors?